# Strange issue when running tests on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, watir

I am trying to run some simple tests on Chrome, and I have followed all required steps to do this. The tests start fine, the Chrome browser opens and is initialized correctly (it seems), but when my tests start to search for objects and check values on the web page.
(e.g. 
    [@browser.div(:id, "example").text.should == "test"] 
or 
    [puts @browser.div(:id, "example").text]
) I get the next error and my tests fail: "Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnkownError:".
This is it, only this message appears, with no clues or details on the error.

I simply do not know were to look for answers. I even tried to debug the tests but with no results.
I even search on known issues on chromedriver, but found nothing.

Another thing to mention is that the tests suite create by me is for cross browser testing.
These tests work fine on Firefox.

Am I doing something wrong in initializing the Chrome browser?
Here is the code from my env file:

```
require "rubygems"
require "rspec"
require "watir-webdriver"
require "watir-webdriver/extensions/alerts"


if ENV["HEADLESS"] then
  include Selenium
  capabilities = WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.htmlunit(:javascript_enabled => true)
  browser = Watir::Browser.new(:remote, :url => "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => capabilities)
elsif ENV["FIREFOX"] then
  browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
elsif ENV["CHROME"] then
  browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
elsif ENV["IE"] then
  browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie
else
  browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
end

Before do
  @browser = browser
end

at_exit do
  browser.close
end
```

I have tried also with the latest release in selenium-webdriver gem, and after this with an older version 2.21.0. Results are the same.

Can you give me a clue what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of chromedriver? http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously I did not checked with the latest version of chromedriver :). 
The version from which the issue stops reproducing is the one from 23 of May 2012.
Thank you for the hint Željko!